# Existem vantagens em se utilizar closures para manter estado ao invés de classes?

Tags: javascript, classes, closures

É muito comum utilizarmos classes para encapsular estado e alguns métodos que o modificam, como este contador:

```js
class Counter {
  #val = 0;
  
  increment(step = 1) {
    this.#val += step;
  }
  
  retrieve() {
    return this.#val;
  }
}

const counter = new Counter();
counter.increment();
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.retrieve()); // 2
```

Mas uma outra forma de se fazer a mesma coisa é manter o estado em uma closure, o que ainda encapsula o estado:

```js
function createCounter() {
  let val = 0;
  
  return {
    increment: (step = 1) => val += 1,
    retrieve: () => val
  };
}

const counter = createCounter();
counter.increment();
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.retrieve()); // 2
```

É claro que vai da preferência de cada pessoa utilizar um ou outro, mas gostaria de saber se o segundo método tem alguma vantagem em relação ao primeiro — que é indubitavelmente mais popular.

Comment: De forma geral não, mas JS tem umas idiossincrasias que pode trazer alguma vantagem, então vou esperar algum com amis autoridade sobre o assunto responder. Em qualquer código normal, de gente normal, em linguagem normal, sempre dá para fazer de uma forma mais simples. Eu acho gambiarra, mas algumas linguagem podem exigir uma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este artigo [How to decide between classes v. closures in JavaScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-decide-between-classes-v-closures-in-javascript/) explica de uma direta e com exemplos, as diferenças entre `closures` e `class` em JS, mas eu vou colocar aqui um resumo do que achei mais interessante a se levar em consideração.

- `closure` e `class` tem comportamentos fundamentais diferentes, onde o closure suporta encapsulamento, sendo encapsulamento um dos principais conceitos da OOP, por outro lado classes em JS nao o suportam. Essa diferença tem de ser levada em consideração para versoes anteriores ao [ES2019](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) onde este tem uma proposta de utilizar var e metodos privados com o uso do `#`, como no seu exemplo. Este recurso está implementado no `babel` e não são todos os navegadores que suportam esse recurso. Sem este recurso de var privadas, nada me impediria de fazer:

```js
class Counter {
        val = 0;

        increment(step = 1) {
          this.val += step;
        }

        retrieve() {
          return this.val;
        }
      }

      const counter = new Counter();
      counter.val = 100; // alterar diretamente o valor de val porque não possui encapsulamento.
      console.log(counter.retrieve()); // 2
```

- Podemos manipular os dados privados da implementação da classe, tornando a implementação da classe mais frágil (para versões anteriores ao ES2019).
- `class` precisam do `new` para criar uma instancia, enquanto que no `closure` basta chamar a função.
- Cada instância da classe compartilha o mesmo protótipo, o que significa que uma alteração no protótipo também afetará todas as instâncias (exemplo abaixo). Enquanto isso, todas as instâncias criadas pela closure são únicas.

```js
class Counter {
        val = 0;

        increment(step = 1) {
          this.val += step;
        }

        retrieve() {
          return this.val;
        }
      }

      const counter = new Counter();
      const counter1 = new Counter();

      Counter.prototype.retrieve = () => 'Hello there!'

      console.log(counter1.retrieve()); // Hello there 
      console.log(counter.retrieve()); // Hello there
```

- E por último, classes são mais eficientes em termos de performance do que o closure, pois a classe cria uma referência na memória onde todas as instancias criadas irão compartilhar a partir desta referência, ou seja, armazena na memória algo em comum que será usado por muitos. Já as closures criam instancias separadas umas das outras, ou seja, cada instancia de uma closure irá criar uma referência única na memória, o que obviamente irá consumir mais memória do sistema.
  Resumindo, se não houver a necessidade de se criar múltiplas instancias de um objeto, `closures` será uma boa opção. Já em caso contrário, `classes` será mais performático, mas deve se atentar para os cuidados para versões do ES que não suportam encapsulamento.

Como voce disse na sua pergunta, cabe ao gosto de cada um decidir o que usar. No começo cheguei a achar que classes eram açucar sintático para closures, mas com o tempo, vi que não é bem assim. Eu particularmente prefiro closure porque me sinto mais a vontade com paradigma mais funcional no JS, mas não ignoro que classes tem seu mérito apesar de ainda ser meio esquisita a implementação no JS. Enfim, espero ter ajudado na sua dúvida e cabe aqui a discussão.