# Existem vantagens ou desvantagens entre se utilizar closures ou classes para atingir injeção de dependência em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, classes, arquitetura-de-software, injeção-de-dependência, closures

Digamos que eu tenha uma função que dependa de um *logger* para funcionar. Para seguir as *"boas práticas"* e atingir um certo nível de desacoplamento, resolvo fazer uso de injeção de dependência para que essa função não dependa de nenhum *logger* concreto, apenas de uma interface pré-definida.

No JavaScript, existem duas principais formas "manuais" (i.e. sem depender de *frameworks* de D.I.) para este fim. Para exemplificar, considere os dois excertos de código abaixo, iguais em funcionalidade:

1. ### Classes

   Uma das opções mais comuns para isso é utilizar classes e injetar a dependência através do construtor:

   ```
   interface ILogger {
     log(data: string): void;
   }

   export class DoStuffClass {
     constructor(logger: ILogger) {
       this._logger = logger;
     }

     doStuff() {
       // ...
       this._logger.log('Deu certo!');
     }
   }
   ```

   E para instanciar, no *main*:

   ```
   // Implementação concreta de ILogger:
   import { Logger } from './logger.ts';

   // Nossa classe:
   import { DoStuffClass } from './do-stuff-class.ts';

   const logger = new Logger();

   const instance = new DoStuffClass(logger);
   instance.doStuff(); // OK. ✔︎
   ```
2. ### *Factory functions*

   Uma outra opção é utilizar uma *factory function* fazendo uso do mecanismo de *closures* do JavaScript:

   ```
   type LogFn = (data: string) => void;

   interface Deps {
     log: LogFn;
   }

   export function DoStuff({ log }: Deps) {
     return function doStuff() {
       // ...
       log('Deu certo!');
     }
   }
   ```

   E para "instanciar", no main:

   ```
   // Implementação concreta da função `LogFn`
   import { log } from './log.ts';

   // Nossa factory function:
   import { DoStuff } from './do-stuff.ts';

   const doStuff = DoStuff({ log });
   doStuff(); // OK. ✔︎
   ```

---

Note que o escopo da pergunta é somente relativo à **injeção de dependência**. Inicialmente não pretendo manter estado, então é indiferente comparar classes ou *factory functions* para esse fim, [**embora seja possível com as duas construções**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/459460/69296).

Enfim, não quero opiniões; se possível gostaria de saber os *fatos*:

- Quais são as vantagens de utilizar construtor de **classes** para injeção de dependência? E as desvantagens?
- E as vantagens (e desvantagens) de visar injeção de dependência com ***factory functions***?